# Antelope Canyon - Do I need to purchase a tour? How to avoid crowds and take good pictures in Antelope Canyon?

Tags: tours, guides, arizona

We are planning a trip to Page, AZ from CA in November. I have been looking around online and it seems like we need to purchase a tour if we want to see the beauty of Antelope Canyon. Is that true? If so, which of the different offers I see online are the best and less crowded tours? If you can suggest a specific tour (i.e. photographers tour) that would be great. 
If there is a "secret" and obviously legal way of seeing the beauty of Antelope Canyon avoiding the crowds, that is also greatly appreciated. We want to take great pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all go in the same quarter mile of canyon, simultaneously. So the only differences are the seating space on the five minute ride, and what you pay.

It is typically badly crowded, sometimes you can’t see the floor- like at a concert. The only way to avoid it is to book one of the special ‘photographers’ tours over noon. You need to have a camera with exchangeable lenses (or they say you are not a photographer), and it’s going to cost you around 100$, or more.

Very ugly, but that’s how it is. There is only so much canyon, and so many people that want to see it.